# Why does my programme not work on other computers with respect to Excel printouts

Tags: excel, vb.net, pia

I have created a programme using Visual Studio 2017 which utilises Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.
All work okay on my machine.
I then compiled a run version which has been loaded on to a friends PC (He has Microsoft 365.)
The programme works okay until I try to run the printouts which use EXCEL as the print mechanism.
He does not seem to have Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll loaded.
My Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll is found in directory “C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c”
On his machine in directory “C:\Windows\assembly" he has Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: While not a solution I know, This is one of the primary reasons I do what ever I can to avoid using Office interops.  If I was you, I would look for alternatives.

Comment: Hursey Thanks. I am looking at other ways of creating the printouts I need.